# How to use MERGE for array properties?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In my neo4j database, I've nodes containing an array, e.g. an array of names, e.g.:

```
CREATE (:Group {names: ['Ben', 'James']})
```

Finally, I can use the following query to find all nodes that contains 'Ben' in the names array:

```
MATCH (n:Group) WHERE 'Ben' IN n.names RETURN n
```

So far everything is fine. But now I want to create a new node if there's no node with `Ben` inside. So what I'm looking for is any function or something like this I can use in the `MERGE` command to create a new node if there's no node with `Ben` in the names array. Something like this:

```
MERGE (:Group {names: contains('Ben')})
```

The idea is that executing the `MERGE`, tries to find any node with Ben in the "names" array and if there's no such node, it creates a new one.

Does anyone know if there's something like this available in cypher?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to model the Person names as separate nodes?

Comment: Do a match where Ben is not in the array of names then do a forEach loop to create a new node

Answer (score 0):

Suggest [apoc.coll](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.coll/) set of functions.

These will allow you to merge, sort collections and also whether a collection contains a specified entity. There latter should address your scenario.

```
apoc.coll.contains(your collection , 'Ben')
```